# How to set SO_REUSEADDR option in zmq::setsockopt() -- if possible, or any workaround?

Tags: zeromq

I am trying to implement an app/thread that listens to an `ipaddr:port` on which another app/thread is already listening. I know I need to update both the apps to set `SO_REUSEADDR` in `setsockopt(...)` before `bind()` to avoid "Address Already in use" error when the 2nd app tries to `bind()`.

The problem is that these apps(libs) are in an existing system that uses ZeroMQ on it's own. I cannot use linux socket lib directly. I have to use ZeroMQ sockets only.

Apparently `zmq::setsockopt()` does not understand `SO_REUSEADDR` as an option as its not defined in the `zmq.h` header. At least there is no `ZMQ_SO_REUSEADDR`

Or may be I am not using the right option.

Can someone help me with this issue. Does ZMQ socket support `SO_REUSEADDR` or not support at all, in which case how to go about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple things going on here.

1. `SO_REUSEADDR` is not going to help you. [[see here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/545332).

`SO_REUSEADDR` will not allow you to share the same socket signature between two applications.  So, if you are bound to a specific `address:port` in your first application *and still using that address and port in that application*, then you will not be able to bind to it in your second application.  `SO_REUSEADDR` allows you to grab an `address:port` signature for a *new* application once an *old* application has given it up but it's still lingering, waiting for the buffer to clear.

2. `SO_REUSEPORT` is what you're looking for [see same link as above].

`SO_REUSEPORT` is intended to allow multiple applications to share the same address signature.  This seems to be what you're looking for.

3. `SO_REUSEPORT` is *not* supported in ZMQ [[see here]](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1443).

You cannot bind to the same `address:port` in multiple applications on the same host in ZMQ.  It's not supported as of June of last year.

... if you wish to *just* handle the case where another service is spinning down and a new service wishes to bind on the same `address:port` signature, you'll have to set ZMQ_LINGER to 0 on the original connection so that it won't hold the socket to clear the buffer.